# QBD V3 says existing customer doesn't exist

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I'm trying to update an existing customer with an ID of QB:7. The customer is returned in the query response, synchronized and active.

Yet, the update request fails. It says that the customer has been deleted!

**REQUEST**

```
<Customer sparse="true" xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
    <Id>QB:7</Id>
    <SyncToken>1</SyncToken>
    <CompanyName>Natalie Chapstick</CompanyName>
    <DisplayName>Natalie Chapstick</DisplayName>
    <PrimaryPhone>
        <FreeFormNumber>415-555-3232</FreeFormNumber>
    </PrimaryPhone>
    <AlternatePhone>
        <FreeFormNumber>(615) 382-8392</FreeFormNumber>
    </AlternatePhone>
    <PrimaryEmailAddr>
        <Address>natalie@samplename.com</Address>
    </PrimaryEmailAddr>
    <BillAddr>
        <Line1>429 Silverbell Ave</Line1>
        <City>East Bayshore</City>
        <Country>USA</Country>
        <CountrySubDivisionCode>CA</CountrySubDivisionCode>
        <PostalCode>94327</PostalCode>
    </BillAddr>
    <ContactName>Natalie Chapstick</ContactName>
</Customer>
```

**RESPONSE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<IntuitResponse time="2013-11-14T01:27:19.771Z" xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
    <Fault type="Validation">
        <Error code="0">
            <Message>
                Operation failed with errors: Customer with id [QB:7] was deleted and cant be modified
            </Message>
        </Error>
    </Fault>
</IntuitResponse>
```

**QUERY RESPONSE**

```
<IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2013-11-14T15:47:18.822Z">
  <QueryResponse maxResults="1" startPosition="1">
    <Customer status="Synchronized">
      <Id>QB:7</Id>
      <SyncToken>1</SyncToken>
      <MetaData>
        <CreateTime>2013-07-04T13:58:17Z</CreateTime>
        <LastUpdatedTime>2013-11-14T01:08:19Z</LastUpdatedTime>
      </MetaData>
      <Organization>false</Organization>
      <GivenName>Natalie</GivenName>
      <FamilyName>Chapman</FamilyName>
      <CompanyName>Natalie Chapstick</CompanyName>
      <DisplayName>Natalie Chapstick</DisplayName>
      <Active>true</Active>
      <PrimaryPhone>
        <FreeFormNumber>415-555-3232</FreeFormNumber>
      </PrimaryPhone>
      <AlternatePhone>
        <FreeFormNumber>(615) 382-8392</FreeFormNumber>
      </AlternatePhone>
      <PrimaryEmailAddr>
        <Address>natalie@samplename.com</Address>
      </PrimaryEmailAddr>
      <DefaultTaxCodeRef name="Tax">QB:1</DefaultTaxCodeRef>
      <BillAddr>
        <Line1>Natalie Chapman429 Silverbell Ave</Line1>
        <Line2>429 Silverbell Ave</Line2>
        <City>East Bayshore</City>
        <Country>USA</Country>
        <CountrySubDivisionCode>CA</CountrySubDivisionCode>
        <PostalCode>94327</PostalCode>
      </BillAddr>
      <ShipAddr>
        <City>East Bayshore</City>
        <CountrySubDivisionCode>CA</CountrySubDivisionCode>
        <PostalCode>94327</PostalCode>
      </ShipAddr>
      <ContactName>Natalie</ContactName>
      <Job>false</Job>
      <CustomerTypeRef name="Wholesale">QB:4</CustomerTypeRef>
      <SalesTermRef name="Net 60">QB:7</SalesTermRef>
      <SalesRepRef name="here">QB:2</SalesRepRef>
      <TaxRateRef name="County, San Thomas">QB:1</TaxRateRef>
      <PaymentMethodRef name="Check">QB:2</PaymentMethodRef>
      <Balance>444</Balance>
      <OpenBalanceDate>2013-10-16</OpenBalanceDate>
      <CreditLimit>5000</CreditLimit>
      <AcctNum>abcdefg12345</AcctNum>
      <JobInfo>
        <Status>Closed</Status>
        <StartDate>2013-11-04</StartDate>
        <ProjectedEndDate>2013-11-29</ProjectedEndDate>
        <EndDate>2013-11-28</EndDate>
        <Description>there is no job to describe</Description>
        <JobTypeRef name="Commercial">QB:1</JobTypeRef>
      </JobInfo>
    </Customer>
  </QueryResponse>
</IntuitResponse>
```

How could that be?

Answer (score 0):

Was this customer created in cloud and had an NG id? Are you trying to access the customer created from V2 in V3?

Comment: No, this was created in QBD. See the new query response above.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify if you are using the correct sync token in the update request.
It should be 1 [ 1 ]

Thanks

Comment: Please see the record query response and the update request bodies. They both have a SyncToken of 1.